# Sharepoint Admin Panel API Access - "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph, sharepoint-app-registration

I was curious whether anyone has seen this message before in the screenshot below. I believe the error prevents the granted API permissions showing as these are not visible, although using the below SPOnline cmdlets says otherwise).

Get-SPOTenantServicePrincipalPermissionRequests
Get-SPOTenantServicePrincipalPermissionGrants

Enable-SPOTenantServicePrincipal
Disable-SPOTenantServicePrincipal

Approve-SPOTenantServicePrincipalPermissionRequest
Deny-SPOTenantServicePrincipalPermissionRequest
Revoke-SPOTenantServicePrincipalPermission

I've been developing an SPFX application and have probably overfiddled by turning on/off the isDomainIsolated parameter in the config.json file and deleting the duplicate Azure App Registrations entries that occur when deleting and adding again the .sppkg file to the app catalogue.

[image]

Any help greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a client side error in the SharePoint Admin center. Regardless of any changes you have made programmatically, this error should not be occurring. You could report the error to Microsoft via a service request. This can be done via the [admin portal or phone](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/contact-support-for-business-products?view=o365-worldwide).

Alternatively, if you are using an older browser, you could try using a modern browser (Google Chrome, Firefox or Microsoft Edge).

Comment: Thanks - my boss has also recommended me to raise a ticket with Microsoft. 

I'll post any correspondence here when I receive it to help others.

Comment: Glad to be of help. If this answered your question, then please mark the answer as accepted.